# Скачки стилей библиотеки chosen

Tags: javascript, css, chosen

Пытаюсь сделать выбор полей с помощью библиотеки `chosen`. Но проблема в том, что когда выбираешь большие элементы, эта планка расширяется вверх, нарушая все стили. Никак не могу найти, как правильно ее ограничить? Чтобы ее размер увеличивался только вниз. Вот код: **[JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/r7a3bazn/2/)** . Пытался вставить его сюда, но встроенный редактор не захотел работать с внешними билиотеками, по крайне мере у меня вылазили ошибки. Также пока никак не пойму, почему она смещается вниз относительно остальных блоков? Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Оберни select в отдельную обертку

Comment: @Air, я думал это сделать через `div`, но или я неправильно сделал, или этот блок просто налез на `textarea`

Comment: Спасибо за оценку...  ))

Comment: @Air, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#wrapTextarea {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px
}

#wrapSelect {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px
}

select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapTextarea">
  <textarea>
</textarea>
</div>
<div id="wrapSelect">
  <select class="chosen" multiple="true" style="height: 34px; width: 280px">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</option>
  <option>ATI/AMD</option>
  <option>NVIDIA</option>
  <option>ATI/AMD</option>
  <option>NVIDIA</option>
</select>
</div>
```